# How to extend character limit in custom html module Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've got a very long table that I need to use with a module. But when I paste the table into the custom HTML module, it limits the amount of characters and cuts the code short. I'm not using any editor.

Tried going to the DB, looked for `_modules`. Followed another suggestion to change Content type from "text" to "mediumtext", but it does not allow me to change it? From the content column, I can only change function or value, but not type. Any ideas?

Attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: You have to log in your database with **phpmyadmin** and change `content` field type to MEDIUMTEXT in `#__modules` table.

Comment: @emmanuel Please check attached screenshot. I can't edit the Type.

Comment: You can't edit that from there, you have to go to `structure` button.

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of these extensions : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules